# Parket Ticket System in Python

Tags: python

I am creating a basic parket ticket system in Python. How can I get my code to do the following:
 - Ask the user how many hours they are staying, take in as an input.
- Have six different cases - 1 hour stay, 2 hour stay, 3 hour stay, 4 hour stay, 5 hour stay and 6 hour stay. 
- Asks user to insert coins into machine. 
- Take what they have paid off the total balance, and keep asking them to insert coins into the machine until their final balance is equal to the total price.
- When they have paid the full balance, output a 'ticket' message to the user.

- I have tried to use if statements to output to the user how much they must pay.
- I have created arrays for the prices and hours - to show how much it costs for a 1 hour stay, 2 hour stay etc.
- I have created an array for the coins that the customer can pay with - doesn't allow any value other than these ones.
- Have tried creating two separate variables, balancePaid and newBalance to keep track of the money left that the customer has to pay.

  ```
  hours = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  price = [1.50, 2.50, 3.50, 4.50, 5.50, 6.50]

  hoursStayed = int;
  hoursStayed = input("How many hours have you stayed")

  if hoursStayed == 1:
      print("Your parking ticket price is " + price[0])

  if hoursStayed == 2:
      print("Your parking ticket price is " + price[1])

  if hoursStayed == 3:
      print("Your parking ticket price is " + price[2])

  if hoursStayed == 4:
      print("Your parking ticket price is " + price[3])

  if hoursStayed == 5:
      print("Your parking ticket price is " + price[4])

  if hoursStayed == 6:
      print("Your parking ticket price is " + price[5])

  balancePaid = input("Please insert coins into machine")


  coins = [2.00, 1.00, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10]

  if balancePaid not in coins:
      print("Sorry, you must only pay £2, £1, 50p, 20p or 10p")


  if balancePaid == coins[0]:
      newBalance = balancePaid - 2.00
      input("You now have to pay " + newBalance)

  if balancePaid == coins[1]:
      newBalance = balancePaid - 1.00
      input("You now have to pay " + newBalance)

  if balancePaid == coins[2]:
      newBalance = balancePaid - 0.50
      input("You now have to pay " + newBalance)

  if balancePaid == coins[3]:
      newBalance = balancePaid - 0.20
      input("You now have to pay " + newBalance)

  if balancePaid == coins[4]:
      newBalance = balancePaid - 0.10
      input("You now have to pay " + newBalance)
  ```
- When user inputs how many hours they are staying, the ticket price is not printed when expected.
- Whenever coins in the array are added into the machine, an error message is still thrown.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python input numbers tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  You're comparing string input with float values; these can never be equal.  This issue has been answered many times on SO ... but I've already voted to close for another reason, so I can't mark the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that your input is coming as `str` variables, but you are comparing the values to `int` (hours) or `float` (coins) variables.

You are using the exact equivalent comparison (`==`) so this would fail because `1` is not exactly the same as `"1"`, etc.

You should convert your input to use the same variable types.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have converted the price[] part to string, and it now works!

Comment: Hi, I am now trying to do a while loop for the program. This is to get the second block of if statements (where the customer is given an input to pay). I want to get this block of if statements to keep repeating until the customer has paid the full balance, so I have set the condition of the while loop to be parkingPrice < newBalance. This isn't working, however. Any ideas of what I can do?

Comment: Just a quick guess without seeing the code: replace the "less than" operator (<) with the "greater than" operator (>) as your parkingPrice variable will never be less than the newBalance.

Comment: Hi @harik2014 - would you mind marking this question as "answered", as a record for other users of the site?